# How to print an array into PDF format customized doc file

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pdf, blob

```
private printCoverLetter(){
    const selectedRows: IUnprintedLookupResult[] = this.getSelectedRows()
    const doc = DocumentCreator.prototype.create(selectedRows);
    Packer.toBlob(doc).then(blob => {
      console.log(blob);
      saveAs(blob, "CoverLetter_" + this.label2 + ".docx");
    );
  }
```

Currently the code above allowed me to print out the selected array into a doc type file as the image below:

[[image: Image link: doc file type]]

We are able to print out. But what Im trying to archieve is: once the user click on the button it will directly download it as PDF and open in a tab.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can look jsPDF https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";

var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFontSize(22);
doc.text(20, 20, selectedRows.map(e => return JSON.stringify(e));
doc.save("myarray.pdf");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information. But this library are not recognizing japanese language :( My clients are from japan, language other than japanese seems like not working

Comment: I know that there are ways to set the font type. but even after i set then the language is still appear in a weird way